# Classic ASP pages showing commented code block in browser

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a few Classic ASP pages which users are viewing. But some users are able to see some of the comment code in the browser

Example:

```
****************** 'New Setup ******************
```

I have checked in Google Chrome and IE 10. How to fix this?

Comment: server side code? client side? why do you add comments if you dont want it to be part of source code esp client side javascript?

Comment: @shahkalpesh [tag:asp-classic] **is** server-side code.

Comment: Anything not written between preprocessor tags *(`<% %>`)* will output as HTML to the client's Internet Browser, if you don't want the comment to show to the end-user add the comment between the preprocessor tags.

Comment: @Lankymart: I know it. How does this `****************** 'New Setup ******************` qualify as comment in classic asp?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I never said it did. OP said *"some of the comment code in the browser"* not me.

Comment: @Lankymart: I never said you said that. Instead of assuming what doesnt look like a vb comment, I asked him whether it is server side or client side javascript?

Comment: @shahkalpesh sorry I'm lost I said the OP *(Original Poster)* said not you. It's fine, the question is unclear, to be honest.

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but presumably you're running your pages on IIS rather than Apache, and presumably you've configured IIS to serve Classic ASP pages.

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP is a server-side processing language as such code written between its pre-processor tags *(`<% %>`)* is processed by the server before any output is sent to the client.

To fix the comment add it inside the pre-processor tags;

```vb
<%
'****************** New Setup ******************
'Code here will run server-side
Response.Write "Hello" 'Will write hello to the client.
%>
<!-- 
Both this comment and the line below are treated as HTML
and will output once the server-side processing has finished.
-->
World
```

Output:

```html
Hello<!-- 
Both this comment and the line below are treated as HTML
and will output once the server-side processing has finished.
-->
World
```

Also, remember that VBScript comments start with a single apostrophe *(`'`)* otherwise it will try to run the comment text.

Comment: how to set document mode to 5 as default in Internet explorer. when i set it as 5 , the page looks fine

Comment: @venkat14 Document Mode has nothing to do with whether the server processed HTML is going to contain a certain string or not but it might affect how it's shown in the browser. I would guess that the string does still appear in the source of the HTML, try looking through the page source in the browser to clarify. To be clear, if you have any text outside of pre-processor tags it will show in the source HTML regardless of how the browser renders it.